# Complicated array function with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tables which look like this:

[image: Link]

I want to filter out the sum of the maximum values in column C for every unique text value in column A, where the value in column B equals "d".

So for the linked example, the result would be a sum of `C3+C6+C9` equaling 9. I am able to get the right results using pivot tables, macros etc., but I'm looking to solve it with a single function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,A1:A9,B:B,"d")/(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1:A9)))
```

`MAXIFS` was introduced with Office 365 Excel

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Any clues on how to do this in older versions of ecxel?

Comment: @Dag I could not find one that did not include a helper column